# ImportError: No module named 'numpy' but it's there! python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What am I missing here? Can someone enlighten me here?

Step 1. I'm trying to install numpy.

> aerin@aerin-HP-Z230-Tower-Workstation:~$ sudo pip install numpy

```
>     The directory '/home/aerin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been
> disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
> executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>     The directory '/home/aerin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.
> check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip
> with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>     Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
>     You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
>     You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Step 2. Ok. it says it's in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`. So let's use numpy.

```
aerin@aerin-HP-Z230-Tower-Workstation:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Step 3. Are you kidding? Let's see where it imports the package.

```
>import site; site.getsitepackages()

['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']
```

You said it's there but it is giving me an ImportError! If anyone hints me where to look, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the permissions of that directory?

Comment: Have you tried using pip's `--no-cache-dir`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you should try:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

If this does not work, try reinstalling numpy for both python2&3

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pip and the reinstall numpy

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install --reinstall numpy
```

Comment: Even if that works, it would be interesting to know the source of Aaron's error.